# Updating Html.Dropdownlists using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I found this solution on here [How to update strongly typed Html.DropDownList using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782815/how-to-update-strongly-typed-html-dropdownlist-using-jquery) and am trying to implement it, but something is bugged in it.

```
$(function() {
    $('#cid').change(function() {
        var selectedCompany = $(this).val();
        var ddl = $("#foid");
        $.post("/TimeTracking/FilterFieldOffices", { companyId: selectedCompany }, function (data) {
            $(ddl).loadSelect(data);
        });
    });
});

(function($) {
    $.fn.emptySelect = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (this.tagName == 'SELECT') this.options.length = 0;
        });
    }

    $.fn.loadSelect = function(optionsDataArray) {
        return this.emptySelect().each(function() {
            if (this.tagName == 'SELECT') {
                var selectElement = this;
                $.each(optionsDataArray, function(index, optionData) {
                    var option = new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);

                    if ($.browser.msie) {
                        selectElement.add(option);
                    }
                    else {
                        selectElement.add(option, null);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

My controller returns a select list of what i want.

```
public ActionResult FilterFieldOffices(int companyId = 0)
    {
        IList<FieldOffice> list = _fodp.GetFieldOfficesForCompany(companyId);

        var returnList = new SelectList(list, "Id", "FacilityName");

        return Json(returnList);
    }
```

I know the .change function is firing by placing alerts, and i know that my controller function is being called through breakpoints, so that narrows it down to the loadselect function, however i cant narrow it down anymore, since no alerts will fire within the load select function. I dont have enough experience with JQuery to form an opinion on whats wrong. So im asking if anyone has had any success on what im trying to do, or if you can see something wrong with the code. 
And before anyone asks, yes i have checked the brackets.

*edit* Forgot to mention that i checked the error console for firefox and i get the error:

```
$(ddl).loadSelect is not a function.
```

*edit* Found a resource that mentions that the error i described arises when you have two conflicting frameworks. So i put in jQuery.noConflict(); and it still does not work.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that "foid" is really the "id" of your `<select>` element?

Comment: @john - Remnant here (got your note). Looking at your code, nothing jumps out at me why you are having an issue. Only difference in my code to yours is that my controller returned a IEnumerable<SelectItemList>. That said, your SelectList looks fine to me...I'll spend a bit more time on this later if i can...

Comment: @remnant not sure if you saw the edits, but its giving an error "$(ddl).loadSelect is not a function" when it is clearly defined. Very strange behaviour :S

Comment: @john - I did see you edit first time around and I don't get that error with my code...i'll take a better look later today and see if I can diagnose the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very bizzare, but i came up with a solution that i can break point through.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#cid').change(function () {
                var coid = $(this).val();
                $.post("/TimeTracking/FilterFieldOffices", { companyId: coid }, function (data) {
                    $("#foid").loadSelect(data); 
                });
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $.fn.loadSelect = function (data) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    this.options.length = 0;
                    $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
                        var option = new Option(itemData.Text, itemData.Value);
                        this.add(option);
                    });
                });
            };
        });

    </script>
```

All i had to do was to wrap the function that wasnt being called in a $(function() { //Code here });
However im still having some trouble. I made a new page for it.

[Refreshing a dropdownlist after elements have been reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965283/refreshing-a-dropdownlist-after-elements-have-been-reset)